# print string before pattern match for a non standard file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have requirement were, whenever the script matches 'host2', I would like it to print the module name (text within square braces) under which the 'host2' is listed. I know grep -B would get text before the string match but my file is does not follow a standard pattern.In this case How to get text in braces which is before the string match?

```
[network]
host1
host2
[webserver]
host1
host9
host7
host5
host6
host2
[db]
host11
host19


Output would be :
network
webserver
```

Comment: http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/05/different-ways-to-print-next-few-lines.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk '/^\[.*\]/{gsub(/[][]/, ""); m=$0} $1=="host2"{print m}' file

network
webserver
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://regexr.com/3gqrt):

```
[\[a-zA-Z]+]((?=[\n\w]+host2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/[\[\]]/,"")}$1~/network|webserver/' file

network
webserver
```